# Why am I getting python3-empy error in mbed studio?

Tags: c++, ros, mbed

I'm trying to integrate rosserial in my embedded code that use mbed.h in mbed studio.

When I try to build my workspace using `catkin_make`, it gives this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:30 (message):
Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
installing the package 'python3-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:164 (include)
/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/home/otonom/BFMC/Embedded_Platform/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.
```

I've tried to update my `CMakeLists.txt` by adding python3-empy to `find_packages()` part by it didn't solve it. How can I solve this?